# How to make pickerView stick to the bottom when using UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have quite large UITableViewController consisting of text fields. I need to present my pickerView at the bottom of the screen. The problem with pickerView is it's scrolling when table is scrolling (because I'v added it as a subview to the tableView). The only option I see is to add this pickerView to the window:

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[window addSubview:view];
```

However, not sure about that and it looks like a hack. Is it safe to use for iOS6+? Does anybody have a more elegant solution for adding pickerView to the bottom of the tableView and making it stick to the bottom?

Before storyboards, I always used generic UIViewController instead of UITableViewController, but my current project uses storyboards and static table views, so I can't use generic UIViewController. The main thing I'm not comfortable with UITableViewController is because its tableView is the root view and there are some nasty problems that you may run (including this one). For example, you cannot place any view on top in center because adding view as subview will end in placing this view in table content and not above. So activity indicators and other custom views cannot stay in center because if you scroll the tableView then these views will also scroll. The solution for adding top-views inside window works from code but you still, you can't add it via storyboards.

Answer (score 1):

First question you should ask yourself: Do you really need a table. You may be far better off with a scroll view, depending on what your table contains and how dynamic its contents is.

Next: If you need to go for a table and need the picker too, that you want to be fixed to the bottom of the screen, then I suggest the following:

1. Create a `UIViewController` `contollerWithPicker` that holds the picker and a container view tableContainer.
2. Create a `UITableViewController` `myTableController` for your table and its content only.
3. Assign myTableController to tableContainer.
4. Depending on your needs, you may want to use either contollerWithPicker or `myTableContoller` as the datasource for your table. Both works nice. Sometimes one is easier to implement and maintain, sometimes the other.

But do not try to mix a table view with fix UI elements outside and independent of the table within the same view.

...........
If it was for the top of the screen, above the table, then you could position your picker within the table's header view.

Comment: A very good point on using scrollView. However, we need some setup from code regarding contentSize in order to use ScrollView (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html). Also, scrollView does not auto resize when keyboard is presented in contract to tableView. So, currently tableView  definitely has some goodies inside if compared to plain ScrollView.